# Timers and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, timer

I have a function which should be called with an interval of 0.5 seconds in its own thread.

Is there a feature in boost or another library which allows to connect a timer which works in callback-like mode and runs callback for a given time interval?

Comment: Are your timing requirments too strict, or your timed function too long, for a sleep(500) loop in the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boost::asio::deadline_timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) for that.

Answer (score 2):

I use JUCE for timers. It allows you to subclass the timer class using multiple inheritance, set a timer running, and then define a callback function to handle the timer events extremely easily.

http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/

There are probably many libs that offer similar functionality.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have already linked boost to my project. I'm sure there is such functionality. Don't really want to link JUCE too. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: No problem. I was thinking that JUCE might be a bit of a sledgehammer for such a small task, but I thought I'd promote its awesomeness anyway :0

Answer (score 0):

sounds more like you want a repeating timer with a callback

you can normally do this with boost and binding...here is a good walk though

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html